# Jupyter Notebook shortcut not appearing in windows 10 start menu under Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

Jupyter Notebook shortcut disappeared from windows 10 start menu under Anaconda.

[Anaconda in Windows Start Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoBOr.png)

I used to have the shortcut earlier, now I either have to launch jupyter from Anaconda Navigator / Prompt. I tried pinning jupyter-notebook application to start but it does not work.

Any suggestions please?